# Passing DurationTickFormat argument fails when done via a struct

Tags: matlab

In Matlab I wanted to pass arguments to the plot function by using a struct. This was going well until I wanted to include the DurationTickFormat argument.
In the minimal example below, I get the following error message when trying to plot the second figure:

> Error using duration/plot There is no DurationTickFormat property on
>   the Line class.

```
clear;
t_dur = days(0);
t_dur(2) = 2;
t_duration = linspace(t_dur(1),t_dur(2),11);

figure;
plot(t_duration,0:10,'Color','k','LineWidth',2,'DurationTickFormat','hh:mm:ss');

% using a struct to pass arguments to the plot function
plotOptions.LineWidth = 2;
plotOptions.DurationTickFormat = 'hh:mm:ss';
figure;
plot(t_duration,0:10,'Color','k',plotOptions);
```

Any ideas why using a struct to pass arguments doesn't work in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: `'DurationTickFormat'` only appears in recent versions of MATLAB.  Which version are you using?

Comment: Notice that using `'DurationTickFormat'` works fine for me in the first case (see code example). Only when passing the `'DurationTickFormat'` argument via a struct gives an error, despite structs working fine for other arguments.

Comment: Ah sorry didn't see that. Weird....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with R2015a, but I have a good guess. I think when you pass a structure, you explicitly add line properties (`lineseries properties` in older matlab, I guess with HG1, `chartline properties` in the newest ones, I'm guessing with HG2). The [chartline properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html) do *not* include `'DurationTickFormat'`. So when you are calling it directly, you are actually telling the `plot` function to do some stuff (like changing the `xlabel` accordingly, which is obviously invisible to a line object).

I hope someone familiar with R2015a can either verify or disprove my hypothesis.

**Update**: from [plot options](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) > `DurationTickFormat`:

> DurationTickFormat is not a chart line property. You must set the tick format using the name-value pair argument when creating a plot.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation.